# C# how to multiThread in Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, threadpool

I put 3 tasks on the list. I want the other 1 to be processed after 2 are done. However, if I put 3 threads in the list after limiting the threads to 3, the chrome driver is not created. My guess is that if there is no free thread, the chrome driver is not created.

It doesn't throw an exception and stops at all.

Does anyone have any idea why the ChromeDriver object is not created when there are no threads?

**testFunction Source**

```
static public void testFunction(object v) 
{
    ChromeDriverService _driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(); 
    ChromeOptions _options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    ChromeDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver(_driverService, _options); //This is Not working    
    Console.WriteLine("This line is not reached.");
}
```

The Action is not Working!(But when I increase the number of threads to 4 it works fine.)

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 1);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(3, 1000);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(testFunction);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(testFunction);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(testFunction);
```

The Action is Good Working!

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 1);
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(3, 1000);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(testFunction);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(testFunction);
//ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(testFunction);
```

Comment: You say you increase the number of threads to 4, but I only see 2 threads being launched?

Comment: It is really curious that the max threads are 3, but 3 threads are not launching. How many cores does your CPU have? How many virtual cores does it have? You are limited to launching and executing concurrent threads based on how many your computer can process at once. And this is limited by the CPU and vCPU cores. But still, it is really curious that increasing the thread count to 4 causes 3 threads to launch.

Comment: maybe.. It seems that one more thread is needed momentarily when creating a chromedriver object. I don't know if it can be solved.